# file to http cxf jax rs routing in camel

Tags: http, apache-servicemix, cxfrs

I am using apache service mix and I am trying to upload file received from FTP to a HTTP Rest Server (CXF JAX RS), basically this would be my camel route

FTP >> File >> HTTP

FTP to file is straight forward and works good ... But I am finding difficulty in sending the received file as an attachment (multipart/form-data) to the CXF JAX RS rest server. I could not set the File as the Exchange body in the route, neither I could set a MultipartBody object myself to the Exchange body - Camel complains that InputStream is expected but found a MultipartBody instead, MultipartBody is not Serializable so I could not send this object as InputStream.

What am I missing to understand ? please help. Any code snippets appreciated.